# R Function for Relative Frequency to all columns

Tags: pearson

Is there an R function that can show me an attribute in the relative frequency to all other attributes of my dataset?

E.g. I want to know from the column "Car-Crash" which contains Yes and No, which of the attributes of the other columns matches the crash column most often with "Yes".

[Dataset for question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGrR2.png)

i know the pearson interval but only for two attributes to calculate correlations.